# Using html5Mode in an Angular SPA inside of wordpress - ngRoute returns a 404

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, .htaccess

My spa is actually just a normal wordpress page using a custom template.

The page slug is /singlepageapp/ so my base: is `<base href="/singlepageapp/">`

Using the $routeProvider I can click around my views no problem, but if I try hit the url cold http://mysite/singlepageapp/singleview I get a 404 due to wordpress not routing these pages via the spa page.

Do I need a special htaccess rewrite rule or how can I get pretty urls in my spa page with out the 404's

My

```
$routeProvider.
when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/wp-content/themes/mytheme/templates/map.html',
    controller: 'VPListCtrl'
}).
when('/:slug', {
    templateUrl: '/wp-content/themes/mytheme/templates/detail.html',
    controller: 'VPDetailCtrl'
}).
otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
});

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a working solution with a wordpress rewrite rule

```
function custom_rewrite_to_spa() {
 $singlepageapp_page_id = 11730;
 add_rewrite_rule( '^singlepageapp\/(.*)\/?', "index.php?page_id={$singlepageapp_page_id}", 'top' );
}

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_to_spa');
```